# Excel VBA not splitting named ranges/rows when using page break in macro

Tags: vba, excel, page-break

Currently I'm trying to print a sheet in pdf in excel and then let a code set the pagebreaks automatically. The code should not break up named ranges in the sheet. The named ranges have multiple rows attached to them, so those rows should stay together on one page under that named range. On this sheet there are also hidden named ranges with rows. The code should not take those in account.

I have tried the code below, but I keep getting an error. See image below the code.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 'Change pages breaks so it is only split on a named range top or bottom
 Dim n As Name
 Dim RngRows() As Integer
 Dim PageBreakRows() As Integer
 Dim NumPageBreaks As Integer
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim TtlRows As Integer
 Dim MaxRowsPerPage As Integer
 Dim strBreakRow As String
 Dim intBreakRow As Integer

 i = 1
 TtlRows = 0
 NumPageBreaks = 0
 MaxRowsPerPage = 17

 'clear any settings that exist
 ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks

 For Each n In ActiveWorkbook.Names

'operate only on ranges that start with RANGE in their name
If Mid(n.Name, 1, 1) = "P" Then

   'if named range is visible
   If Range(n).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
   Debug.Print "Processing Range " & n.Name & " with #"
   Rows = " & Range(n).Rows.Count"
   'add # rows in range to row count.
    TtlRows = TtlRows + Range(n).Rows.Count
    'if rount count larger than max allowable add a page break
        If TtlRows > MaxRowsPerPage Then
        'take first row of current named range and add page break
        ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Range(Range(n).Rows(1).Address)
        'update Totl row count
        TtlRows = Range(n).Rows.Count
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print "Range hidden: " & n.Name & " with # rows=" & Range(n).Rows.Count
    End If 'end visible check
 End If 'end name check
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

All the references are correct.
So I have no idea what is wrong here. Does anybody know the solutions? Or know a better code from experience?

New image after deleting line: "Rows = " & Range(n).Rows.Count" "
[image]

Comment: How is the variable Rows declared? Do you use Option Explicit?

Comment: Add to your declarations `dim Rows As Long`

Comment: @RichHolton, If you mean the variable named ranges/rows; they are declared by searching with the MID function. Or is that not what you mean?

Comment: @DavidG I tried it, but now I get a "type mismatch" on the same row that is yellow in the image.

Comment: Do not use `Rows` as a variable.  Change the name to something else. Also I do not see where you use that variable, so why have it?

Comment: "Declared" means "where are they instantiated with a `Dim` statement?"

Comment: My bad, `Row` really is not used at all. Comment that line out. Thank you @Scott for pointing that out.

Comment: That line by itself will raise the out of memory error. `Rows` is a semi-reserved keyword in Excel's object model.

Comment: Delcare ALL variables with `Dim` statement (or `Const`, `Public`, etc where applicable). Best way to ensure you do this is to add `Option Explicit` at top of each module, and you will have to work through the compilation errors as a result of undeclared variables.

Comment: By declared, I mean "Dim" or similar. Option Explicit, on the first line of any code module, will flag an error for any variable that is not declared. This is a best practice, and many problems can be avoided by declaring all  variables.

Comment: Wasn't that line of code the one that was triggering your error?

Comment: So I deleted the line that gave me the error. The code now runs but not in the way that I want it to run. See the edited question.

Comment: As far as I can see. The code is working till line: "Debug.Print "Processing Range " & n.Name & " with # rows =" & Range(n).Rows.Count". In the intermediate I can see the correct number of rows counted within the named ranges.

Comment: @RichHolton yes that was the line triggering the error. I fixed the error, but now the code only inserts a page break after the first named range. Which is not what should happen. It should make a page break after the named range that is within 17 rows on a page.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Have you tried stepping through the code (F8 in the Visual Basic Editor)?

Comment: @RichHolton, Yes I have tried that. I have got the code working now. Seems to be that it relies on the word you enter in the mid range function. I defined only one letter, the code referred to all named range with that specific letter. I then entered a more specific word and the code work as it should be.